# Ruby on Rails best_in_place gem throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am following the guide on https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place
When I run my app I get the error below: What does this mean???

```
%table
  - @schedules.each do |s|
    %tr
      %td= best_in_place s, :name

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'best_in_place'`

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove app/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js

Include activating code in view:

```
%table
  - @schedules.each do |s|
    %tr
      %td= best_in_place s, :name
:javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the code in your original post?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to ensure that the `best_in_place` gem is installed to your environment and the JavaScript file is being imported to your HTML. If you're using the asset pipeline (Rails 3.1+), you can include it in your JavaScript manifest:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place
```

Then, ensure that the script has an HTML DOM element(s) that it can bind to and execute the `best_in_class` function upon:

```
# in your view
<div class="best_in_class"></div>
```

Comment: Are you still receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'best_in_place'`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include best_in_place lib before using it

```
//= require best_in_place
```

to your `appplication.js` file

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error.  I restarted the server and it worked for me.

Comment: I was not able to determine the exact cause of this, but that may have been what worked for me too.